# Android Kotlin - viewBinding Type mismatch: inferred type is DrawerLayout but ConstraintLayout was expected

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm trying to get viewBinding to work.

This is the code:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view: ConstraintLayout = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

I manually declared the type `ConstraintLayout` because it's what I'm using for that activity called `AskProfileImage`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#303030"
    tools:context=".AskProfileImage">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView97545"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo2" />
```

But I'm getting the error

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is DrawerLayout but ConstraintLayout was expected
```

on

```
binding.root
```

how to fix this?

Comment: You can try rebuilding. If you Ctrl-click the word `root` it will take you to the xml where it was defined. This will quickly tell you if you mistakenly imported the wrong binding or accidentally declared the wrong view type or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

viewBinding creates a class for each activity. So in my case for this activity it's:

```
ActivityAskProfileImageBinding
```

So the correct code is:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityAskProfileImageBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityAskProfileImageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Since viewBinding is probably broadly used now, I don't understand why the hell nobody could answer that and why google docs are as always useless